# Replace the data in HTML by dynamically changing data from array (JS / JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an array of objects I have processed. I also created a menu with elements that has a multilevel structure. I am trying to replace the created elements with dynamic data from my array (like if it is happening from the backend - my data `const` may change).

Is there any option to replace the data inside the menu according to the data from my array? I have already tried inserting `innerHTML` but I have a lot of problems in the console regarding it. I get this error:

> Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

I know that there is a lot of code so I've created this Codepen in order to show how my menu works: https://codepen.io/baser78/pen/mdxZxMa

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Дети",
    groups: [{
        id: 2,
        name: "Имеющие редкие заболевания",
        groups: [{
            id: 3,
            name: "Spina Bifida",
            groups: []
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            name: "Буллёзный эпидермолиз",
            groups: []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        name: "С инвалидностью",
        groups: []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "Профессиональные сообщества",
    groups: []
  }
];

const m = data;

// здесь будет flat array из массива данных
let arr = [];

// для каждой группы вызываем рекурсивную функцию
for (let group of m) {
  recurgroups(group, 0);
}

// RECURSIVE FUNCTION
function recurgroups(group, parentID) {
  arr.push({
    name: group.name,
    id: group.id,
    parentID: parentID
  });

  if (group.hasOwnProperty("groups") && group.groups.length > 0) {
    for (let subgroup of group.groups) {
      recurgroups(subgroup, group.id);
    }
  }
}

//menu code
const pageHeader = document.querySelector(".funding-categories");
const toggleMenu = pageHeader.querySelector(".toggle-menu");
const menuWrapper = pageHeader.querySelector(
  ".funding-categories__menu-wrapper"
);
const level1Links = pageHeader.querySelectorAll(
  ".funding-categories__level-1 > li > a"
);
const listWrapper2 = pageHeader.querySelector(
  ".funding-categories__list-wrapper:nth-child(2)"
);
const listWrapper3 = pageHeader.querySelector(
  ".funding-categories__list-wrapper:nth-child(3)"
);
const subMenuWrapper2 = listWrapper2.querySelector(
  ".sub-funding-categories__menu-wrapper"
);
const subMenuWrapper3 = listWrapper3.querySelector(
  ".sub-funding-categories__menu-wrapper"
);
const backOneLevelBtns = pageHeader.querySelectorAll(".back-one-level");
const isVisibleClass = "is-visible";
const isActiveClass = "is-active";

toggleMenu.addEventListener("click", function() {
  menuWrapper.classList.toggle(isVisibleClass);
  if (!this.classList.contains(isVisibleClass)) {
    listWrapper2.classList.remove(isVisibleClass);
    listWrapper3.classList.remove(isVisibleClass);
    const menuLinks = menuWrapper.querySelectorAll("a");
    for (const menuLink of menuLinks) {
      menuLink.classList.remove(isActiveClass);
    }
  }
});

for (const level1Link of level1Links) {
  level1Link.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const siblingList = level1Link.nextElementSibling;
    if (siblingList) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.classList.add(isActiveClass);
      const cloneSiblingList = siblingList.cloneNode(true);
      subMenuWrapper2.innerHTML = "";
      subMenuWrapper2.append(cloneSiblingList);
      listWrapper2.classList.add(isVisibleClass);
    }
  });
}

listWrapper2.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const target = e.target;
  if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "a" && target.nextElementSibling) {
    const siblingList = target.nextElementSibling;
    e.preventDefault();
    target.classList.add(isActiveClass);
    const cloneSiblingList = siblingList.cloneNode(true);
    subMenuWrapper3.innerHTML = "";
    subMenuWrapper3.append(cloneSiblingList);
    listWrapper3.classList.add(isVisibleClass);
  }
});

for (const backOneLevelBtn of backOneLevelBtns) {
  backOneLevelBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const parent = this.closest(".funding-categories__list-wrapper");
    parent.classList.remove(isVisibleClass);
    parent.previousElementSibling
      .querySelector(".is-active")
      .classList.remove(isActiveClass);
  });
}



/*this code i'm trying to use to display elemnts inside the menu*/

const level0 = arr.filter(item => item.parentID == 0).map(item => '<div data-id="' + item.id + '" value="' + item.name + '">' + item.name + '</div>')

document.querySelector('s1').innerHTML = '<div value="0">Select an item</div>' + level0.join('')


document.querySelector('s1').addEventListener('change', function() {
  let thisID = this.divs[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-id')

  const level1 = arr.filter(item => item.parentID == thisID).map(item => '<div data-id="' + item.id + '" value="' + item.name + '">' + item.name + '</div>')

  document.querySelector('s2').innerHTML = '<div value="0">Select an item</div>' + level1.join('')

})


document.querySelector('s2').addEventListener('change', function() {
  let thisID = this.divs[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-id')

  const level2 = arr.filter(item => item.parentID == thisID).map(item => '<div data-id="' + item.id + '" value="' + item.name + '">' + item.name + '</div>')

  document.querySelector('s3').innerHTML = '<div value="0">Select an item</div>' + level2.join('')

})
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 100%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

button,
a {
  color: inherit;
}

.notification {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  background: var(--yellow);
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .notification {
    display: none;
  }
}


/* HEADER STYLES
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

.funding-categories {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #302f2d;
}

.funding-categories .funding-categories__topbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60px;
}

.funding-categories .funding-categories__topbar .brand {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.funding-categories .funding-categories__topbar .social {
  display: flex;
}

.funding-categories .funding-categories__menu-wrapper {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0;
  width: 340px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.funding-categories .funding-categories__menu-wrapper.is-visible {
  display: block;
}

.funding-categories .funding-categories__list-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}

.funding-categories .funding-categories__list-wrapper:nth-child(2),
.funding-categories .funding-categories__list-wrapper:nth-child(3) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.funding-categories .funding-categories__list-wrapper:nth-child(2).is-visible,
.funding-categories .funding-categories__list-wrapper:nth-child(3).is-visible {
  transform: none;
}

.funding-categories .funding-categories__list-wrapper:nth-child(1)>ul>li>.sub-menu,
.funding-categories .funding-categories__list-wrapper:nth-child(2) .funding-categories__level-3 {
  display: none;
}

.funding-categories .funding-categories__menu-wrapper li+li {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.funding-categories .funding-categories__menu-wrapper a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.funding-categories .funding-categories__menu-wrapper a.nested {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.funding-categories .funding-categories__menu-wrapper a:hover,
.funding-categories .funding-categories__menu-wrapper a.is-active {
  color: var(--orange);
}

.funding-categories .funding-categories__menu-wrapper a:hover::before,
.funding-categories .funding-categories__menu-wrapper a.is-active::before {
  content: "✦";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: var(--orange);
}

.funding-categories .back-one-level {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.funding-categories .back-one-level svg {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="funding-categories">
  <div class="funding-categories__topbar funding-categories__showmore">
    <button class="toggle-menu" type="button">
      <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M20 11V29" stroke="#999999" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" />
        <path d="M11 20H29" stroke="#999999" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" />
        <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="39" height="39" rx="19.5" stroke="#E6E6E6" />
      </svg>
      Выбрать ещё
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="funding-categories__menu-wrapper">
    <div class="funding-categories__list-wrapper">
      <ul class="menu funding-categories__level-1">
        <li>
          <a href="" class="nested">Дети</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu funding-categories__level-2">
            <li>
              <a href="" class="nested">Имеющие редкие заболевания</a>
              <ul class="sub-menu funding-categories__level-3">
                <li>
                  <a href="">Spina Bifida</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="">Буллёзный эпидермолиз</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="">С инвалидностью</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="" class="nested">Профессиональные сообщества</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="funding-categories__list-wrapper">
      <button type="button" class="back-one-level">
        <svg width="10" height="12" viewBox="0 0 10 12" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M7.47412 11L2.49141 6L7.47412 1" stroke="#999999" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        </svg>
        <span>Back</span>
      </button>
      <div class="sub-funding-categories__menu-wrapper"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="funding-categories__list-wrapper">
      <button type="button" class="back-one-level">
        <svg width="10" height="12" viewBox="0 0 10 12" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M7.47412 11L2.49141 6L7.47412 1" stroke="#999999" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
        </svg>

        <span>Back</span>
      </button>
      <div class="sub-funding-categories__menu-wrapper"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: In your **querySelector** calls you refer to S1, S2 and S3. Those aren't valid elements so they will need to be either classes (start with a period) or IDs (start with the pound sign). However, your code doesn't have those used anywhere.

Comment: Also, you're removing HTML element `.funding-categories__level-2` with `document.querySelector('.funding-categories__level-1').innerHTML`  and then trying to add an event listener to it.

Comment: What is the `divs` in `this.divs[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-id')`. And where are the `SELECT` elements you're apparently trying to use `this.selectedIndex` on?